# How to handle two onClicks in the same component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

There are two custom popups with OK and Cancel.
When you click the OK button, a review is written, and it is a code that is sent to the server as a post request. Then, the confirmation button appears once more, and a pop-up indicating that the writing is complete is displayed to the user. My problem here is that the post request is sent, but I don't get a second popup stating that the writing is complete.

[image]

The picture above is a pop-up design I made.

This code is the parent component.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const token = cookie.parse(context.req.headers.cookie).accessToken;
  const reviewId = context.query.reviewId;
  const viewLecture = await getViewLecture(reviewId, token);

  return {
    props: { token, reviewId, viewLecture },
  };
}

const WriteMentee = ({ token, reviewId, viewLecture }) => {
  const [reviewInfo, setReviewInfo] = useState([]);

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false);

return (
    <>
      <section className={styles.contentSection}>
        {modal ? (
          <ModalWithBackground
            setModal={setModal}
            className={styles.modalHeight}
          >
            <ReviewModal
              mainText={"후기 등록"}
              subText={"작성한 후기를 등록하시겠습니까?"}
              cancelBtn={setModal}
              confirmBtn={async () => {
                const res = await writeReviewAPI(
                  token,
                  reviewId,
                  content,
                  score
                );

                if (res == 200 || res == 201) {
                  console.log("200 || 201");
                  setConfirm(!confirm);
                }
              }}
            />
            {confirm ? (
              <ConfirmModal
                mainText={"후기 등록"}
                subText={`후기 등록이 완료되었습니다.\n수강하시느라 고생 많으셨습니다.`}
                confirm={() => {
                  router.push("/mentee/mypage/menteeReview");
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              <></>
            )}
          </ModalWithBackground>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
        </section>
    </>
   )
```

This component is the component of the first popup image.

```
const ReviewModal = ({ mainText, subText, cancelBtn, setConfirm }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <article className={styles.roundModal}>
        <h3 className={styles.title}>{mainText}</h3>
        <p className={styles.subTitle}>{subText}</p>

        <div className={styles.btnSection}>
          <button className={styles.cancel} onClick={cancelBtn}>
            <span>취소</span>
          </button>
          <button className={styles.check} onClick={() => setConfirm(false)}>
            <span>확인</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  );
};
```

This component is the component of the second popup image.

```
const ConfirmModal = ({ mainText, subText, confirm }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <article className={styles.roundModal}>
        <h3 className={styles.title}>{mainText}</h3>
        <p className={styles.subTitle}>{subText}</p>

        <div className={styles.confirmSection}>
          <button className={styles.confirm} onClick={confirm}>
            <span>확인</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: What errors are you getting if any? is this supposed to be a multi-step process?

Comment: After pressing the OK button on the first popup, the second popup should appear. This should be done in multiple steps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use your `confirm` state to handle which content is showing.

```
<ModalWithBackground
  setModal={setModal}
  className={styles.modalHeight}
>
  {confirm ? (
    <ConfirmModal
       mainText={"후기 등록"}
       subText={`후기 등록이 완료되었습니다.\n수강하시느라 고생 많으셨습니다.`}
       confirm={() => {
         router.push("/mentee/mypage/menteeReview");
       }}
     />
   ) : (
    <ReviewModal
      mainText={"후기 등록"}
      subText={"작성한 후기를 등록하시겠습니까?"}
      cancelBtn={setModal}
      confirmBtn={async () => {
        const res = await writeReviewAPI(
            token,
            reviewId,
            content,
            score
            );
         if (res == 200 || res == 201) {
           console.log("200 || 201");
           setConfirm(!confirm);
         }
       }}
     />
   )}
</ModalWithBackground>
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.. 

Comment: Oh noes. Still receive the same behaviour and does not change the modal content?

Comment: Thanks for your help! In the end, I solved it by pulling out the confirm component once more :)

Answer (score 0):

On your parent component, you are passing a confirmBtn prop, which you should be calling in the onClick on the first modal, and doesn't take any arguments. That should handle the opening of the other modal.
But in the ReviewModal, you call a different function called setConfirm and pass it false. You should just be calling confirmBtn (although the name might not matter if you're not using TS). But no need to pass it an argument since that's all handled by the parent component.
Just pass the onClick handler the method itself and change the props to take in confirmBtn instead of setConfirm.

```
<button className={styles.check} onClick={confirmBtn}>
            <span>확인</span>
          </button>
```

And then also double check the api call is returning 200 just in case!

Comment: It would have been nice if I had seen the answer earlier.. I'm very sorry. I'll make it by referring to the answer when refactoring. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by writing code like this

```
{modal ? (
          <ModalWithBackground
            setModal={setModal}
            className={styles.modalHeight}
          >
            <ReviewModal
              mainText={"후기 등록"}
              subText={"작성한 후기를 등록하시겠습니까?"}
              cancelBtn={() => {
                setModal(false);
              }}
              confirmBtn={async () => {
                const res = await writeReviewAPI(
                  token,
                  reviewId,
                  content,
                  score
                );

                if (res == 200 || res == 201) {
                  console.log("200 || 201");
                  setConfirm(!confirm);
                }
              }}
            />
          </ModalWithBackground>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}

        {confirm ? (
          <ModalWithBackground
            setModal={setModal}
            className={styles.modalHeight}
          >
            <ConfirmModal
              mainText={"후기 등록"}
              subText={`후기 등록이 완료되었습니다.\n수강하시느라 고생 많으셨습니다.`}
              confirm={() => {
                router.push("/mentee/mypage/menteeReview");
              }}
            />
          </ModalWithBackground>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).